# Logical truthness in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What does the `true?` says actually?
`(true? 0)`=`false`. `(if 0 "0 is true" "0 is false")`=`0 is true`.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing two things:

- the different *values* that there are in Clojure, and
- the way that `if` and its progeny treat these values.

`true` and `1` are values, and they are different:

```
(= true 1) ; false
```

But they have the same effect as first arguments to `if`:

```
(if true "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Hello!"

(if 1 "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Hello!"
```

In fact, almost any first argument causes `if` to evaluate and return its second argument:

```
(if + "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Hello!"

(if *ns* "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Hello!"

(if String "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Hello!"
```

There are only two *values* that cause `if` to evaluate and return its *third* argument. Those two values are `false` and `nil`.

```
(if false "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Goodbye."

(if nil "Hello!" "Goodbye.") ; "Goodbye."
```

If no third argument is supplied, it defaults to `nil`:

```
(if false "Hello!") ; nil
```

The same distinction between values applies to the other Clojure conditionals, which are - directly or indirectly - derived from `if`: `if-not`, `when`, `when-not`, `and`, `or`, &c. These are expressed as macros, so that, like `if`, they do not evaluate their arguments until they need to.

To quote the [official documentation](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(if%20test%20then%20else?))

> **(if test then else?)**
>
> Evaluates `test`. If not the singular values `nil` or `false`, evaluates and yields `then`, otherwise, evaluates
>   and yields `else`. If `else` is not supplied it defaults to `nil`. All
>   of the other conditionals in Clojure are based upon the same logic,
>   that is, `nil` and `false` constitute logical falsity, and everything
>   else constitutes logical truth, and those meanings apply throughout.

Answer (score 7):

In Clojure, `nil` and `false` are treated as "false" and everything else is considered `true`, that explains the behaviour of the `if` expression in your question.

On the other hand, the [`true?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/true_q) predicate is `true` only if supplied with a `true` value.

For more information, take a look at this [article](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-truthy-and-falsey.html) discussing the Truthy and Falsey concepts in Clojure.

Comment: this means the value of 1 isn't true. and what does the `(boolean 1)` yield, if it is not the value?

Comment: and also the value of `nil` is true in `(false? nil)`?

Comment: Please _do_ read the linked article, you have to understand that in Clojure we have "truthy" and "falsey" values. That means that `1` isn't `true`, but it _is_ truthy. `(boolean 1)` is performing a coercion, as stated in the documentation. And `(false? nil)` is `false`, because `nil` isn't `false`, although it's _falsey_.

Comment: I find it helps of think of `true?` and `false?` as akin to `nil?` and `zero?`.  That is, they are predicates that check for a single specific value (`true` or `false`).

Answer (score 2):

The question is already solved, yet I wish to add a helpful analogy for other readers that may come here.

`true?` performs a type-sensitive comparison. In some languages there is a concept of "strict equality" (i. e. `===` in JavaScript or `eql?` in Ruby) that checks whether the values are not only equal by **value**, but also equal by **type**.

A live example from Ruby: consider numeric values `0` and `0.0`. `0` is an **integer** literal, `0.0` is a **floating-point number literal**. While they do have equal **numeric values** (both zero) and will behave (mostly) the same in arithmetic expressions – they are instances of different classes and are not **strictly** equivalent (i. e. their string representations are different, which could be a problem in certain applications).

As such, `true` and `1` are equal **by value** in a sense of **boolean value**, so wherever data is interpreted as a boolean (i. e. in `if`), they result in the same effect. But they're obviously different values.

`nil` as a boolean is **false**. However, if you're working with **nullable boolean** (i. e. boolean that may be unset), you can't rely on it being `false` just because it triggers a first branch of `if-not`, this may result in a hole in your application's logic. For that, you could use `false?`. Or design your system differently, of course.

Comment: Your analogy doesn't quite translate, I think. 1. `true?` tests whether its argument is *the same thing* as `true`. It could have been defined `(defn true? [x] (identical? x true))`. Having the same value and type may not be enough. For instance, `(identical? [1] [1])` is `false`. 2. In Clojure, `(= 0 0.0)` is `false`. But some things of different types *are* considered equal: `(= [\1 \2] (seq "12"))` is `true`. ...

Comment: ... 3. To say that *`if` interprets its first argument as boolean* is confusing. In Java, `boolean` is the type of `true` and `false`. Clojure uses the term *logical* to refer to the distinction that `if` draws. Clojure's `boolean` function *almost* returns a logical equivalent. Unfortunately, you can create Java `Boolean`s that Clojuire `if` and `boolean` treat differently: `(boolean (Boolean. false))` is `false`, whereas `(Boolean. false)` acts true under `if`: `(if (Boolean. false) 1 2)` is `1` 4. Java `boolean`s are not nullable. `Boolean`s, the boxed equivalent, are.

Comment: @Thumbnail 1. Primitive types. Since only one `true` of this type is possible, it doesn't make a difference. Just as there is only one integer `0`. Vectors are not primitives. 2. This doesn't concern `true?` at all. `=` behaves differently depending on given types' `equals` implementation. `true?`'s implementation is type-independent. 3. And that behavior is not considered a bug? Any rationale? Regardless, I wasn't talking about Java's types, I was considering a possibility of getting a value of `true`, `false` or `nil` at a certain point of execution and need for a proper condition to branch.

Comment: 1. Your conclusion is correct but the argument is unsound: the vector example shows that `identical?` and `true?` do not depend on type comparisons 2. The point is that Clojure `0` and `0.0` are unequal *values*, in any meaningful sense. By contrast, `(= (bigint 0) 0)` is `true` 3. You are using the word *boolean* in a sense other than Java's and Clojure's.

Comment: 4. I agree. For me, it's a bug.  Rich Hickey vehemently defends the way `if` works , but surely `boolean` should be consistent with it. Again, the Clojure idiom for (explicitly) using boxed booleans is ... don't! Then the *possibility of getting a value of `true`, `false` or `nil`* does not arise.

Comment: @Thumbnail 1. If the conclusion is correct, it's of no use to discuss this further. 2. In context of Clojure, maybe. However, they are both different representations of the **same number**, albeit with different capabilities. 3. Yes, you've called it "logical", which is a "real-world boolean" to me, outside the context of Clojure. 4. Not familiar. Cannot comment :)

Comment: I agree that further discussion is useless.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answer, some test code!

```
; a simple way to define two functions that give the "truthy" or "falsey"
; value as an actual boolean (i.e. either the value 'true' or the value
; 'false' for an arbitrary Clojure 'thing'. These functions are _total_
; (i.e. defined for everything and never raise exceptions or return nil)

(defn truthy? [x] (if x true false))
(defn falsey? [x] (if x false true))

; Some test code
; https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html

(require '( clojure test ))

; clojure.test/is checks whether the value it is given is "truthy", not
; whether it is equal to the boolean 'true'!

(clojure.test/is true)  ; passes 
(clojure.test/is 1)     ; passes
(clojure.test/is 0)     ; passes
(clojure.test/is ())    ; passes
(clojure.test/is nil)   ; ** fails **
(clojure.test/is false) ; ** fails **

; We will perform explicit comparison against the boolean values instead of
; testing for truthyness.

; WHAT'S FALSE?
; The function 'false?' gives 'true' only on 'false'
; Anything else is 'NOT false' (but not necessarily 'true') 

(clojure.test/is (= false (false? '()     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? []      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? {}      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? #{}     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? nil     )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (false? false   ))) ; only false is false
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? true    )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? 0       )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? 1       )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? "false" )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? "true"  )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? ""      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? (fn []) ))) ; yeah that's far-fetched
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? (Boolean. false)))) ; an evil boxedJavaFalse is NOT false
(clojure.test/is (= false (false? (Boolean. true))))  ; an evil boxedJavaTrue  is NOT false

; WHAT'S TRUE?
; The function 'true?' gives 'true' only on 'true'
; Anything else is 'NOT true' (but not necessarily 'false') 

(clojure.test/is (= false (true? '()     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? []      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? {}      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? #{}     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? nil     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? false   )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (true? true    ))) ; only true is true
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? 0       )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? 1       )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? "false" )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? "true"  )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? ""      )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? (fn []) ))) ; yeah that's far-fetched
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? (Boolean. false)))) ; an evil boxedJavaFalse is also NOT true
(clojure.test/is (= false (true? (Boolean. true))))  ; an evil boxedJavaTrue  is also NOT true

; What's TRUTHY?
; Every 'thing' is 'truthy' except 'nil' and 'false'

(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? '()     )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? []      )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? {}      )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? #{}     )))
(clojure.test/is (= false (truthy? nil     ))) ; only nil and false are not truthy (i.e. falsey)
(clojure.test/is (= false (truthy? false   ))) ; only nil and false are not truthy (i.e. falsey)
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? true    )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? 0       )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? 1       )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? "false" )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? "true"  )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? ""      )))
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? (fn []) ))) ; yeah that's far-fetched
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? (Boolean. false)))) ; an evil boxedJavaFalse is also truthy
(clojure.test/is (= true  (truthy? (Boolean. true))))  ; an evil boxedJavaTrue  is also truthy

; What's FALSEY?
; By construction, no 'thing' is 'falsey' except 'nil' and 'false'

(map (fn [x] 
         (clojure.test/is (= (falsey? x) (not (truthy? x))))
     )
     [ () [] {} #{} nil false true 0 1 "false" "true" "" (fn []) (Boolean. false) (Boolean. true) ]
)

; "not" of a 'thing' yields exactly "falsey?" of thing

(map (fn [x] 
         (clojure.test/is (= (falsey? x) (not x)))
     )
     [ () [] {} #{} nil false true 0 1 "false" "true" "" (fn []) (Boolean. false) (Boolean. true) ]
)

; "not∘not" of a thing yields exactly "truthy?" of a thing
; this corresponds to JavaScript's "!!" -- "bang bang, you are a boolean!"
; which, given an object, yields that object's truthy boolean value. 

(map (fn [x] 
         (clojure.test/is (= (truthy? x) (not (not x))))
     )
     [ () [] {} #{} nil false true 0 1 "false" "true" "" (fn []) (Boolean. false) (Boolean. true) ]
)
```